# IS it possible to set the width of a td at client side as well as server side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a problem in setting the width of the  element both at server and client side. At client side the css is not overriding the applied css from server side. All I need to do is add css to td at server side, and client side remove the old css and apply the new css.

Here is my code

Design Page

```
 <td id="tdlblOverRideText" runat="server">
         <asp:Label ID="lblOverRideText" Text="Overridden charges are denoted by green background" runat ="server" Visible ="false" BackColor="#efffff"></asp:Label>    
     </td>
```

Server side:

tdlblOverRideText.Attributes.Add("class", "OverRideText");

Clientside:

```
    $("#tdlblOverRideText").removeClass("OverRideText");
    $("#tdlblOverRideText").addClass("OverRideTextHide");
```

CSS

```
td.OverRideText {
    font-style:italic;
    text-align:right !important;
    padding-right:1%;   
}
td.OverRideTextHide {
    font-style:italic;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:10%;   
}
```

Since its a lazy loading I cannot use

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "text", "jsmethod();", true);
```

because this will call the js method on second time load and not for the first pageload.

Comment: Couldn't you just call jsmethod() from your javascript on the page load?

Comment: Thats what I mentioned. our application is designed for lazy loading. first time on page_Load,  calling javascript method the control value is undefined in .JS file. Second time it does. I tried almost everything.

Comment: What are you using for the lazy load? By any chance is it: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
//check from 10 to 10 seconds if you have  you class somwhere on dom
var mytick = setInterval(animationFunction, 1000)


function animationFunction() {
  console.log("tick");
    if ($(".OverRideText").length > 0)
    {
       $(".OverRideText").removeClass("OverRideText").addClass("OverRideTextHide");
      
      //here you can destroy the loop if you want
      //clearTimeout(mytick)
    }
}

var step=0;
 setInterval(function() {
   step++;
  console.log("lazy load");
  $('#wrapper').append('<div class="OverRideText">Text ' + step + '</div>');
}, 1000);
```

```css
.OverRideText {
    font-style:italic;
    text-align:right !important;
    padding-right:10%;   
}

.OverRideTextHide {
    font-style:italic;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:50%;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="OverRideText">Text 0</div>
  </div>
```

I've been using javascript interval execution to check if element having class='OverRideText' can be found; why not id? because inserting with lazy loading same id is incorrect in html. Another lazy load trick (to simulate a lazy load) is inserting elements with that class at a interval of 10 seconds.

Now back to the main problem your lazy load most be performed with ajax, ajax get has success event, **in success event you can perform what animation you like.**